# Is this a good practice: Converting string to int?

Tags: c++

I want to know if converting **`string`** to **`int`** by using **`stoi`** to make it work with switch is not effecting the behavior of a program.
I am using string because I am validating user input by using asci table for this `>= 48 && <= 57` method but not includes in this code to make it short.

The code:

```cpp
    do
       {
          cout << "Choice: ";
          string userChoice;
          cin >> userChoice;
          isValid = validNum(userChoice);
          if(isValid)
          {
             int intUserchoice = stoi (userChoice);
             switch(intUserchoice)
             {
             case 1:
                ServerStart();
             }
          }
       }while (!isValid);
```

Comment: You can use it simply safely, but there are more effective ways.[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

Comment: This seems basically fine, although there's not enough details to say for sure. I would suspect that `validNum` and `stoi` are a bit redundant, but the basic pattern of validating user input, converting it to an integral or enumerated type, and switching on that result is valid.

Comment: @Саша Ok ) all clear

Comment: @NathanPierson Ok, all clear, This is just a simple validation that user must only enter integrals/numbers ) I have not include the not needed code

Comment: Right, it's just my speculation that the implementation of `validNum` is very similar to the scanning that `stoi` later performs on the string and that some amount of work is effectively being done twice. Not in a way that should make the program incorrect, though.

Comment: You can also validate user input with `stoi` directly by catching `std::invalid_argument` and `std::out_or_range` exceptions

Comment: @Ranoiaetep That might incorrectly accept something like `"1.7"` as valid input. Without knowing what exactly `validNum` is checking, it's hard to say what an equivalent check done entirely in `stoi` would look like.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes I agree but I like simple solutions for simple problems )

Comment: @NathanPierson yes exactly that's why I am using asci table for this job.  >=48 && <=57 method

Comment: @Ali-Baba It might be better to use `>='0' && <= '9'` for better clarity, or use `std::isdigit`

Comment: _I like simple solutions for simple problems_ Wouldn't this be simpler?: `if (cin >> intUserChoice) { switch (intUserChoice) { ... } } else { cerr << "Wrong input!"; }` (Of course, you still have to add the code to clear the error state and ignore the wrong input in error case. For this, you will find a lot of answers here as well.)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes but both are same 0 && 9  or 48 && 57

Comment: @Scheff Yes, actually I have declared global function for validation and I am just recalling it whenever needed )

Comment: @Ali-Baba right, but `>='0' && <= '9'` is way more readable than `>=48 && <=57`.

Comment: Well, but you asked for good practice... ;-)

Comment: @StefanRiedel Yes, I agree but I have learnt this function with  >=48 && <=57 and becomes my habit :D

Comment: @Scheff Yes I totally agree )

Comment: Do you want to usw switch/case because you like it more than if/else or do you make use of `case`s where you don't `break` or `return`?

Comment: @hansmaad Yes I have not forget about break or return )

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that the conversion to a numeric type only makes sense, if you handle the user input as some kind of
numeric sequence. Like "If the choice was one of the options below the 3rd". You will then implement
it with a switch/case or mulitple ifs like these examples:

```
void handleChoice1(string userChoice) {
    int intUserchoice = stoi(userChoice);
    switch(intUserchoice) {
        case 1:
            ServerStart();
            // Heads up, no break here
        case 2: 
            StartSomethingElse();
            break;
        case 3:
            // more stuff..
    }
}

// which is equivalent to this:

void handleChoice2(string userChoice) {
    int intUserchoice = stoi(userChoice);
    if (intUserchoice <= 1) {
        ServerStart();
    }
    if (intUserchoice <= 2) {
        StartSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

If there is only a simple logic for each choice, I see no reason to not just compare the input string
to expected options and handle an unexpected input. If this is the only "menu" you'll have to implement
I would just go with a simple if/else. Of course this does not scale to big and complex menus, but
for simple things this is fine.

```
void handleChoice3(string userChoice) {
    if (userChoice == "1") {
        ServerStart();
    }
    else if (userChoice == "2") {
        StartSomethingElse();
    }
    else {
        error("Invalid input");
    }
}
```